# SetbackgroundResource from xml crashes VM, Out of memory. How can i optimise this?

Tags: java, android, animation, memory

I am currently making a small application in Android.
My wish is to have two ImageViews that change their animation when i click different buttons on the screen.

First a sample xml: (the drawables are 250x350y .png files)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/main_idle_kf1" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/main_idle_kf2" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/main_idle_kf3" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/main_idle_kf2" android:duration="500" />
</animation-list>
```

Example of my code

```
ImageView _imgView1; //declared in oncreate = ((ImageView) findViewById... etc)
AnimationDrawable _aniDrawable1;
```

OnResume:

```
_imgView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim_main_idle);
_aniDrawable1 = (AnimationDrawable) _imgView1.getBackground();
_aniDrawable1.start();
```

---

So far this works, and there are no issues. The little sprite does it's jig.
I am however doing this to two imageViews at a time, and I've been trying to add more/different "frames" in the XML for each. However, i do not have to add many frames, before the VM crashes because it's out of memory.

It seems to me as if it's making a bmp out of each drawable mentioned in the XML, and then binding this in the VM memmory when i call "setBackgroundResource".

My question: Is there any way to make this less memmory intensive? Can i change how .setBackgroundResource saves the data from the XML? 7-8 different pictures like the one in my xml is enough to break a 16MB VM.
I dont want much, i just want a few frames of animation running side by side that change when i click buttons, but that seems prettymuch impossible if AnimationDrawable eats so much out of the VM-memmory.

Hints? ideas? alternatives?

Comment: Did you ever find the a solution for this? I have resized all of my images to smaller sizes, but that is not a good enough solution. I would like to do more complex animations with more frames, but the memory issue prevents this.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this article - [Loading large images](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Particularly look at "Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory" section

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping your image resources in `/drawable-nodpi`
Android might be assuming resources as `/drawable-mdpi` as default.